# Change image labels when using pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I am loading an image dataset with pytorch as seen below:

```
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('...', transform=transform)
loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batchsize)
```

The dataset is i na folder with structure as seen below:

```
dataset/
  class_1/
  class_2/
  class_3/
```

So in result each image in class_1 folder has a label of 0..etc.

However i would like to change these labels and randomly assign a label to each image in the dataset. What i tried is:

```
 new_labels = [random.randint(0, 3) for i in range(len(dataset.targets))]
 dataset.targets = new_labels
```

This however does not change the labels as i wanted due to some errors later in model training.
Is this the correct way to do it or is tehre a more appropriate one?

Comment: What is the exact issue? What errors do you get?

Comment: @GoodDeeds If ichange the labels to 0 and 1 as seen above and change the output neuron to 1 i get out of bounds regarding the target(label) which means the labels are still 0-2 after the change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a transformation for the labels:

```py
import random

class rand_label_transform(object):
  def __init__(self, num_labels):
    self.num_labels = num_labels

  def __call__(self, labels):    
    # generate new random label
    new_label = random.randint(0, self.num_labels - 1)
    return new_label

dataset = datasets.ImageFolder('...', transform=transform, target_transform=rand_label_transform(num_labels=3))
```

See [`ImageFolder`](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html) for more details.

Comment: This produces : AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'shape', regarding the line ridx = torch.randperm(labels.shape[0])